Creating a 15.x backwards-compatible backup with Microsoft SQL Server 2022
I've created a database backup using Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (v16.00.1135). When trying to restore this backup on another machine, I got the following error:

The database was backed up on a server running version 16.00.1135. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 15.00.2000. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

I've taken a look through the options while creating a backup via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 20, and found no obvious indicators of how I can make sure the backup is backwards-compatible with 15.x when my server is running 16.x.
Is it possible to create a backup from SQL Server 16.x that is compatible with SQL Server 15.x?

see https://www.reddit.com/r/SQLServer/comments/16r2at1/restore_sql_server_2022_db_into_2019_server/

Quite simply: you CANNOT. SQL Server backups have never been backwards compatible - you need to use the same (or a newer) version on the machine where you want to restore your data to ...

See the duplicate on [dba.se]: Restoring a backup to an older version of SQL Server

Bacpac is usually the way to go these days

The only way I have found is to migrate restore it to a same version of the server and then generate scripts to complete the restore.  This can be done via powershell library like dbatools or SSMS using a process like: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/
